IIS Server stops i.e application just showing to reloading all the time and did not respond
I have an application that is deployed on the IIS Server, but often it stops responding and just looking like it is reloading always.
After restarting the application in IIS manager on remote desktop, it works fine.
I see the logs and everything but I never know the exact issue that is causing to stop the application for always and it remains down until I restart using iis manager.
If anyone knows the solution please resolve my issue.
Nazar
I want to have the solution to my problem so that it can be resolved like the website that is deployed should not stop responding.

Check if you are using any Database or its connection, might be they are not responding well.

Make sure that the server has sufficient resources, such as memory, CPU, and disk space, to support the normal operation of the application. If the server resources are insufficient, it may cause the application to stop responding. You can use performance monitoring tools to analyze the performance of applications and servers to identify any bottlenecks or performance issues and take appropriate actions to optimize performance.
